# Relative staleness of a record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have votes in my system, but I want to sort by some calculation of votes and freshness of the item.

I know that in SQL, it should be quite easy to do something like this - with `GETDATE()`, `DATEDIFF()` and a bit of math magic.

How would I go about doing this in Mongo? Will it require to use map-reduce? I remember hearing that map-reduce is blocking - so it's not recommended for high-traffic website page queries?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MongoDB you can sort on the value of any of the fields in a document, but you can't sort on a calculated value.

However, in this case, couldn't you just sort on the date (descending) instead of the freshness? Wouldn't that give the same sort order?

Comment: Yes, but I want to take votes into account - I don't want a new item with a vote of 1 to be higher than yesterday's item with 100 votes

Comment: If all you need to do is sort, maybe you can sort on the client after retrieving the data. If you want to use the result of the temporary calculation to filter out some of the results, maybe you will have to use map reduce. The thing to keep in mind with map reduce is that since it uses Javascript only one map reduce can run at a time (that's a limitation of the Spider Monkey Javascript engine used).

Comment: I don't want to rely on map-reduce because of the reason you mentioned. I need this for paging the results, How can this be done in the client side? Seems to me like I'd need to fetch a lot more items than the page size and then show only some of them, feels awkward

Comment: Maybe you can precompute the value you want to sort on once a day at off peak hours and then just sort on the precomputed value. Not many alternatives since the MongoDB query language doesn't support computed intermediate values.